# Read all lines of textstream including first line

Tags: excel, vba

While trying to read lines from a text file with `.CL` extension.
It does not read from first line.
Link to .CL file is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eNIJtBGw91Ta2fhe_06tOkKfgHacuGQF/view?usp=sharing

I tried reading single line as well as all lines.
I also tried changing `format` property of `OpenTextFile` method. But I am not able to read from First line.

```
Private Function txt2array(ByRef fileNames() As String) As String()
'On Error Resume Next
Dim i As Long
Dim commentline, templine As String
Dim oFSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim oFSTR As TextStream

Dim iCount As Long: iCount = 0          'declaring and initializing it
Dim temp() As String

'loop through all file names
For i = 1 To UBound(fileNames)
    Set oFSTR = oFSO.OpenTextFile(fileNames(i), 1, -1)
    tempdata = oFSTR.ReadAll
    MsgBox tempdata
    oFSTR.Close
Next i
End Function
```

I need to read from the first line. I am not understanding what i am missing. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Have you tried `For i = 0 To UBound(fileNames)`?

Comment: Read from the first line of what?  Also, why have you selected `CreatefromBoolean=True` in the `OpenTextFile` method? Especially since you are only reading a file that should exist? In any event, either way, I read all of the lines of the file using `.ReadAll`